# Netbeans ignores jars installed in .m2

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am facing a strange issue with Netbeans 8.2

I have installed a jar using command line `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=wlclient.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle.weblogic -DartifactId=wlclient -Dversion=12.1.3.0 -Dpackaging=jar`

In the project I have the dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
      <artifactId>wlclient</artifactId>
      <version>12.1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The projects builds fine with `mvn clean install` in my console

When I am executing from Netbeans "*clean and build*" I can see that in the output it executes `cd /<path to project>/; JAVA_HOME=/<path to java>/jdk1.8.0_181 M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.5.3 /opt/apache-maven-3.5.3/bin/mvn clean install` but it fails with message "*class file for weblogic.i18n.logging.MessageLoggerRegistryListener not found*" which indicates that it cannot find the installed jar above.

Any ideas why this is happening?

ps. I am using CentOS Linux 7 and Oracle JDK

Thanks

Comment: Did you check your local M2 repository? Is the jar installed and named as you think it should?

Comment: @CrazySabbath Yes, and the project build fine through the terminal with mvn clean install. This is what drives me nuts :)

Comment: I am sure you've tried this, but will ask anyway: does your project compile at all? because it seems if JAR was missing, it wouldn't? `mvn compile`

Comment: @CrazySabbath yes, it compiles fine from my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans uses an embedded Maven as default which has it's own repository, settings, etc.

Did you switch it to use the same one you use from the command line?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I have configured Netbeans to use an external one and from the logs I see it uses the same so no luck with that as well :/

Comment: Add this to your Maven configuration: -Dmaven.repo.local=path/to/my/other/repository